# Change add to cart button with something else " How to Buy"

Tags: cart

I am new to magento commerce and would really appreciate to answer to question how/what extension install to change the "Add to Cart" button to something like "How to Buy" and redirected to some other page and hide price for that product. Example on this site:

chelleon(dot)co(dot)uk

1. they hide the price
2. change to "How to Buy" and redirect to some other page.

I really appreciate your help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For hiding price is easy you can comment price displaying code in below file.

catalog/product/view.phtml

and place "how to buy" button.

But for "how to buy" button if its cms page link than you can add it by adding it below on button click:

```
 <?php echo $this->getUrl('Your cms page identifier'); ?>
```

But if it changing product wise than i suggest add one product attribute and add that url in that attribute and get it on view.phtml.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i dont want this "How to Buy" on all of my products i wanted on selected products or categories. I have been looking lots of extension and could not find proper solution yet.

Comment: OK..if you want to do it for some of products than you can add one "yes/no" attribute to products and if its yes than hide "addtocart" and show cms page url.

Comment: thanks a lot Hardik, your suggestions were very helpful.